как бороться с вредоносными процессами kcached
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как быть в данной ситуации?
У меня есть сервер главного сайта на linux.
При мониторинге подключений и пару манипуляций я выявил вот такую хрень
tcp        0      0  
172.16.0.7:34642     <->   213.171.212.212:443     ESTABLISHED 7906/[kcached]

Подскажите нормально ли это или нет?
что это за [kcached]?
Читал в инете так и не понял - очень много воды.
Буду признателен, заранее спасибо!
